# Jquery Select css Class :before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I select an css class in jquery (or javascript), if it looks like this:

```
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {}
```

So far I got this:

```
$('.funkyradio[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
```

But I do not know how to further approach.

Comment: class name is `funkyradio-success` or `funkyradio`?

Comment: You can't select the ::before specifically as it's not technically a DOM element. (see previous SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

You can however select that actual element with 

`$('.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label').click();`

Comment: so no way to get ::before?

Comment: @JohnDoesLegacy have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/4202224) answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Assuming `funkyradio` is the css class name. Put space between `funkyradio` and `[type=checkbox]` as checkbox is a child of funkyradio-success

```
$('.funkyradio [type=checkbox]').click(function() {
```